# Swift: Can not change the imageView frame, the imageView is in the storyboard

Tags: swift, frame, ios-autolayout

There is an ImageView named scrubberImageView, which is in the storyboard, and I have set its height and width height percentage and centerX. When I set the center of scrubberImageView in the method viewDidAppear(), it failed and it showed with the frame which is set in the storyboard. But When I user the code bellow, the frame will be set correctly.

```
delay(0.1) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.scrubberImageView.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y:self.scrubberImageView.center.y)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
```

I have no idea if there is another way to solve this method, I have tried to use the code bellow.

```
self.scrubberImageView.updateConstraints()
```

Do you guys have some methods to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to combine auto-layout constraints with manual frame layouts. I would strongly discourage this.

If you want to move an image view around either don't use auto-layout to position it in the first place and manually calculate and set its desired size, or animate the constraint values instead.

Expanding on the latter, the centerX constraint you have, assuming it has a constant of 0, will position the image view in the middle of its superview.

If you add an outlet to this constraint, you can change its constant in code. Setting this to 20 will move the image view 20pts to the right (as it's offsetting the centerX by 20), and setting it to -20 will, you guessed it, move it 20pts to the left.

After any constraint changes in code you should always call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` to apply your changes, otherwise you won't see them!

See the following example, which animates an image 50 points to the right:

```
self.imageViewCenterX.constant = 50
UIView.animate(duration: 5) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Notice how I only include the call to `layoutIfNeeded` in the animation block, it is not necessary to include the constant value setting here.

Animating back to center is just a case of setting the value to 0 and calling `layoutIfNeeded` as above!